# SELECT previous group value based on conditions in Google Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, lag

The goal is to populate the value of the previous group for all applicable rows and include conditions. Consitions are specified in the `STATUS` column. The query needs to be adjusted for condition `STATUS = A`.

Data Looks Like this:

```
DATE        ID   VALUE       GROUP_ID   STATUS
2021-06-01  1   New York       1          A
2021-06-02  1   New York       1          A
2021-06-03  1   New York       1          B
2021-06-04  1   New York       1          A
2021-06-05  1   Boston         2          A
2021-06-06  1   Boston         2          A
2021-06-07  1   San Francisco  3          A
2021-06-08  1   San Francisco  3          A
2021-06-09  1   New York       4          A
```

Intended Result:
Data Looks Like this:

```
DATE        ID   VALUE       GROUP_ID   STATUS  PREVIOUS_VALUE
2021-06-01  1   New York       1          A           NA
2021-06-02  1   New York       1          A           NA
2021-06-03  1   New York       1          B           NA   
2021-06-04  1   New York       1          A           NA
2021-06-05  1   Boston         2          A         New York
2021-06-06  1   Boston         2          A         New York
2021-06-07  1   San Francisco  3          A         Boston
2021-06-08  1   San Francisco  3          A         Boston 
2021-06-09  1   New York       4          A         San Francisco
```

Attempts till now

```
select *, last_vale(VALUE IGNORE NULLS) OVER (partition by ID, GROUP_ID order by DATE) from ( 
table)A
```

```
select *, lag(VALUE) OVER (partition by ID, GROUP_ID order by DATE) from ( 
table)A
```

I have a backup plan to create a table which will hold unique values based on conditions and then can run `UPDATE` statements based on the nearest smaller `GROUP_ID` but would rather have a more sustainable solution in place.

Thanks.

First Modification: Exclude Destination Titled 'Boston'
I tried to use case when value not in ('Boston') then ...

```
DATE        ID   VALUE       GROUP_ID   STATUS  PREVIOUS_VALUE
2021-06-01  1   New York       1          A           NA
2021-06-02  1   New York       1          A           NA
2021-06-03  1   New York       1          B           NA   
2021-06-04  1   New York       1          A           NA
2021-06-05  1   Boston         2          A         New York
2021-06-06  1   Boston         2          A         New York
2021-06-07  1   San Francisco  3          A         San Francisco
2021-06-08  1   San Francisco  3          A         San Francisco
2021-06-09  1   New York       4          A         San Francisco
```

Comment: What do you mean "adjusted for status = 'A'"?  That seems to have nothing to do with your desired results.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have modified the draft as 'First Modification' so that Boston is excluded from the computation altogether. I have a list of destinations that need to be ignored for such a computation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a window frame specification?

```
select t.*,
       max(value) over (order by group_id
                        range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding
                       ) as prev_value
from t;
```

If the `group_id`s are sequential but have gaps, then you can use `dense_rank()` to get one that works:

```
select t.*,
       max(value) over (order by dense_group_id
                        range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding
                       ) as prev_value
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by group_id) as dense_group_id
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have modified the draft as 'First Modification' so that Boston is excluded from the computation altogether. I have a list of destinations that need to be ignored for such a computation. Thanks